# Condition between duplicated values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-loc

Every customer is duplicated when they have more than one plan. I want to set the status to the customer:

If they have every product with 'canceled_at' filled, the customer status is cancelled, but when it's not every product with the canceled_at filled, but at least one, the status is 'downgrade' because he lost a product.

```
customer|canceled_at|status
x       |3/27/2018  |
x       |           |
y       |2/2/2018   |
y       |2/2/2018   |
z       |1/1/2018   |
a       |           |
```

I already have the canceled status, now i only need the downgrade

```
df['status']=(df.groupby('customer')['canceled_at'].
  transform(lambda x: x.notna().all()).map({True:'canceled'})).fillna(df.status)
```

```
customer|canceled_at|status
x       |3/27/2018  |downgrade
x       |           |downgrade
y       |2/2/2018   |canceled
y       |2/2/2018   |canceled
z       |1/1/2018   |canceled
a       |           |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible compare column for no missing values and grouping by `Series` `customer` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html),
[`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test all values `True`s (all non missing) or at least one value not missing (any non missing) and pass it to [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
g = df['canceled_at'].notna().groupby(df['customer'])
m1 = g.transform('all')
m2 = g.transform('any')

df['status'] = np.select([m1, m2],['canceled','downgrade'], np.nan)
print (df)
  customer canceled_at     status
0        x   3/27/2018  downgrade
1        x         NaN  downgrade
2        y    2/2/2018   canceled
3        y    2/2/2018   canceled
4        z    1/1/2018   canceled
5        a         NaN        nan
```

Or:

```
df['status'] = np.select([m1, m2],['canceled','downgrade'], '')
print (df)
  customer canceled_at     status
0        x   3/27/2018  downgrade
1        x         NaN  downgrade
2        y    2/2/2018   canceled
3        y    2/2/2018   canceled
4        z    1/1/2018   canceled
5        a         NaN
```

---

If only `NaN`s groups need convert to `downgrade`:

```
mask = df['canceled_at'].notna().groupby(df['customer']).transform('all')
df['status'] = np.where(mask,'canceled','downgrade')
print (df)
  customer canceled_at     status
0        x   3/27/2018  downgrade
1        x         NaN  downgrade
2        y    2/2/2018   canceled
3        y    2/2/2018   canceled
4        z    1/1/2018   canceled
5        a         NaN  downgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

def select_status(canceled):
    c = canceled.count()
    if c == 0:
        status = ''
    elif c == len(canceled):
        status = 'canceled'
    else:
        status = 'downgrade'
    return pd.Series(status, index=canceled.index)

df = pd.DataFrame({'customer': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'a'],
                   'canceled_at': ['3/27/2018', None, '2/2/2018', '2/2/2018', '1/1/2018', None]})
df['status'] = df.groupby('customer')['canceled_at'].apply(select_status)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  customer canceled_at     status
0        x   3/27/2018  downgrade
1        x        None  downgrade
2        y    2/2/2018   canceled
3        y    2/2/2018   canceled
4        z    1/1/2018   canceled
5        a        None
```